# FBRequestConnection filters ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to filter out certain pages via their ID? I have an array of ID page to be filtered, and I would do so before the request and not later.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:
[NSString stringWithFormat:
@"search?type=place&center=%f,%f&distance=%i&limit=%i&offset=0", latitude, longitude,(int)distanceFromCenter,queryLimit] completionHandler:^
...
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by filter our page IDs? You have certain IDs that you don't want the FBRequest to return in returned results?

Comment: @ArminM exact, I have an array of IDs that I do not want in the results. Thanks